# Extracting variables from fit statistics parameters after curve fitting using lmfit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am using lmfit to plot a Gaussian fit against my data. I want to extract just one of the variable parameters (eg: I0 ) and store it in an array.
Any suggestions to would really help.
I have attached my sample code below:

```
def Gauss(x,I0,x0,sigma,Background):
            return I0*exp((-(x-x0)**2)/(2*sigma**2))+Background   
mod=Model(Gauss)
result=mod.fit(yData,x=xData,I0=1,x0=mean,sigma=sigma,Background=1)
result.plot()
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x,y,z distribution')
plt.ylabel('PL intensity')
basename=os.path.basename(file)
plt.title(basename)
print('The fit statistics for',basename)
print(result.fit_report()) 


[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 264
    # data points      = 30
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 8379722.68
    reduced chi-square = 322297.026
    Akaike info crit   = 384.203840
    Bayesian info crit = 389.808629
[[Variables]]
    I0:          6128.15928 +/- 343.334644 (5.60%) (init = 1)
    x0:         -5.1147e-07 +/- 3.1252e-08 (6.11%) (init = -4.039265e-07)
    sigma:      -7.4953e-07 +/- 6.0842e-08 (8.12%) (init = 9.136697e-07)
    Background:  1730.50204 +/- 338.181818 (19.54%) (init = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reading the lmfit documentation and going through some of the examples might help.  On SO, the expectation is that you would show what you tried and what may not have worked as you expected.

You say:

> I want to extract all the variable parameters (eg: I0 ) and plot it against my data and visualise the error bars for my fits.

The resulting parameters are in `result.params`, a dictionary with keys of parameter names and values of lmfit.Parameter, which will have multiple attributes.

If you want just the best-fit parameter values, you might try

`print(result.params.valuesdict())`

For more, consult the docs.

I'm not sure what you mean by "plot it against my data and visualise the error bars for my fits."

You also say:

> I also want to compute the variable parameters for each of my data points and store in an array.

Perhaps you mean that you would like the array values for the model?  If so, that's in `result.best_fit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M Newville. What i meant was I want to extract just one of the variable parameters (I0). I tried to print(result.I0), it does not work. Please let me know how I can access just one of the variable parameters in my above code. Thanks very much once again!

Comment: @AngelaMary this is already answered: **... `result.params`, a dictionary with keys of parameter names and values of lmfit.Parameter.**.   Seriously, read the documentation and go through the examples.

Answer (score 0):

@AngelaMary,
I also stumbled upon this problem. After some research I found out print(result.params['I0'].value) would print the value of 'I0' and print(result.params['I0'].stderr) would spit the corresponding error value.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32719223)

Comment: @TobiasSchäfer why do you think print `(result.params['I0'].value)` won't extract the value of the parameter? I believe @AngelaMary wanted to extract any one of the parameters in the provided example.